# How to simplify this code logic? (Reverse conditions some time)

Tags: c

I want a bool to determine whether the if condition needs to be reversed, I use my most straight forward way to write this but seems looks dirty!

```
bool isReverseCondition=true;
int a=0;
bool myCondition=a>0;
if(isReverseCondition){
    myCondition=!myCondition;
}
if(myCondition){
    printf("OK!");
}
```

It looks dirty, especially need a temp variable "myCondition" to store my actual condition, also it appears not only once! I know it is simple but have no idea to rewrite :(

Can anyone give suggestion?

Comment: `if (a > 0 != isReverseCondition)` should work.

Comment: As `isReverseCondition` is always `true`, you can simply write `if ( ! (a>0) ) printf("ok");`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I think the OP wants to be able to change `isReverseCondition` without changing the `if` afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the xor operator like

```
bool myCondition = (a > 0) ^ isReverseCondition;
```

Comment: *xor* [requires iso646.h in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#cite_note-synonyms-2)

Comment: @ringø Thanks for the comment, I am used so much with C++ (in which it is a keyword), and I had the (false) impression that the question is tagged C++. Edited. It seems it is part of C99 if I'm not wrong, right, as it was added in 1995?

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing one of the `if` statements with a ternary operator:

```
bool isReverseCondition = true;
int a = 0;
bool myCondition = isReverseCondition ? a <= 0 : a > 0;
if (myCondition) {
    printf("OK!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
bool myCondition = (isReverseCondition ? !(a>0) : (a>0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `bool myCondition = !(a > 0);` should work too, because first the expression in brackets will be calculated, and only then it will be reversed. Basically what your code does. The checking of isReverseCondition is unnecessary because it is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Could you reduce it to:

```
 int main(  )
{
  bool isReverseCondition = 0;
  int a = 0;
  bool myCondition = a > 0;

  myCondition = isReverseCondition;

  if ( myCondition )
    printf( "OK!" );
  else
    printf( "NOT OK!" );
}
```